# Add Element to Document and find with XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, domdocument

I have code that searches XML Documents (org.w3c.dom) using namespace-aware XPath. I am having issues with adding elements to the document and then being able to find them via the XPath.

If I add the elements and search using the XPath I do not get any result. However, if I convert the Document to a String and reparse to a Document, the XPath finds the element.

I create the XPath as follows:

```
String myXPathQuery = "/ns1:element1/ns2:element2/ns3:element3";
XPathFactory fact = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = fact.newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(myNSContext);
XPathExpression myXPathExpression = xpath.compile(myXPathQuery);
```

I am adding the element as follows:

```
Document doc = ...;
Element elementToWhichToAdd = ...; // this is "ns2:element2"

Element newElement = doc.createElement("ns3:element3");
elementToWhichToAdd.appendChild(newElement);
```

If I run the above XPath against this Document it doesn't find anything. But if I reparse the Document the XPath works.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

As part of the process by which I update the document I add the Namespace if it does not exist (it usually does not).

```
Element rootElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
NamedNodeMap map = rootElement.getAttributes();
if (map.getNamedItem("xmlns:ns3") == null)
     rootElement.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns", "xmlns:ns3",
            "urn:exo:/path/to/xsd/in/jar");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Element newElement = doc.createElement("ns3:element3");
```

`createElement` is a DOM level 1 method that is not namespace aware - [its JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#createElement%28java.lang.String%29) says that it returns

> A new `Element` object with the `nodeName` attribute set to `tagName`, and `localName`, `prefix`, and `namespaceURI` set to `null`.

You need to create the new elements using the DOM level 2 [`createElementNS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#createElementNS%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead

```
Element newElement = doc.createElementNS("urn:exo:/path/to/xsd/in/jar", "ns3:element3");
```

(or whatever is the correct namespace URI that corresponds to `ns3`, you could get it directly from the namespace context using `myNSContext.getNamespaceURI("ns3")`).

Comment: I have tried several variations of the above with no luck. `("urn:ns3", "ns3:element3")`, `("xmlns:ns3", "ns3:element3")`. See the post edit regarding the addition of the NSs. When I do any of the above the element is in the form of `<ns3:element xmlns:ns3="urn:ns3".../>`

Comment: @JohnB from the code you've edited in I would think `createElementNS("urn:exo:/path/to/xsd/in/jar", "ns3:element3")` would be what you're looking for.

Comment: My friend, you rock! Thank you!